# Saving samples in eCognition

Tags: nearest-neighbor, ecognition

In eCognition developer is it possible to save samples that I have selected for nearest neighbor classification with the workspace or project? Every time I close and reopen my project I have to re select NN samples.

Answer (score 1):

Just save the ruleset (Develope Ruleset Mode ("4" in the toolbar)) to a file you like. The samples are saved along with the ruleset.